# SQl Delete top 100 from table

Tags: sql

I am trying to delete the all but the most recent 3,000 items in a table.  The table has 105,000 records.

I am trying this, but an error is generated incorrect syntax.

```
delete tRealtyTrac where creation in( select top 103000 from tRealtyTrac order by creation)
```

Comment: Didn't anyone else notice that 105,000 minus 103,000 = 2,000 ? He said "I am trying to delete the all but the most recent 3,000 items in a table." He was about to delete a 1000 more records than he wanted.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The delete syntax is going to be slightly different from what you have. An example would be:

```
DELETE FROM tRealtyTrac
WHERE creation in( select top 103000 creation from tRealtyTrac order by creation)
```

Notice how there is the "from" keyword. This is saying we want to delete from the table called tRealtyTrac

The one problem I foresee with this is, you are probably going to want to not use creation...

Instead:

```
DELETE FROM tRealtyTrac
WHERE someuniqueidcolumnlikeakeyofsomesort in( select top 103000 someuniqueidcolumnlikeakeyofsomesort from tRealtyTrac order by creation)
```

Otherwise you may delete more than you intended.

Comment: Creation could be the same in the 103001st and 103000th member.  I'd select the top PK ID and check that in it.

Comment: thanks guys- I used this command combining your answers

delete tRealtyTrac where id in( select top 103000 id from tRealtyTrac order by creation)

Answer (score 4):

The inner query needs to be:

select top 103000 **creation** from ...

Comment: This is correct.  Thank you.  Marked Brian's answer as correct because the full syntax and explanation is provided.

Answer (score 4):

As for me, CTE is the better solution for ordered deletion

```
;WITH records_delete AS (
    select top 103000 creation 
    from tRealtyTrac 
    order by creation)
DELETE records_delete
```

Answer (score 2):

A super easy way to do this:

1. select top 3001 from tRealtyTrac order by creation desc
2. take the last one's date then delete tRealtyTrac where creation < 'thedateyoufound'

But Andy has a good idea too.
;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM tRealtyTrac WHERE creation IN (SELECT top 103000  * FROM tRealtyTrac ORDER by creation)
```

You forgot the fields in tRealtyTrac (I used an asterisk to select all but you can make a list of them or only one). You also forgot the FROM clause.

Comment: your statement fails because creation cannot be IN all attributes of tRealtyTrac. Although, you have mentioned that one has to change the asterisk, the statement gives wrong knowledge to a reader.