# Make a delete statement delete rows as soon as it find it, rather than keeping the table static until delete is finished

Tags: sql, algorithm, t-sql, delete-row

I'm wondering if there is a way to get a delete statement to remove rows as it is traversing a table. So where now a delete statement will find all the appropriate rows to delete and then delete them all once it has found them, I want it to find a row that meets the criteria for deletion and remove it immediately then continue, comparing the next rows with the new table that has entries removed.

I think this could be accomplished in a loop...maybe? But I feel like it would be horribly inefficient. Possibly something like, it will look for a row to delete, then once it finds a single row, it will delete, stop, and then go through for deletion again on the new table.

Any ideas?

Comment: No this isn't possible as stated. Tell us the exact problem you are trying to solve not your proposed solution.

Comment: Put this in a loop  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809294/sql-delete-top-100-from-table  And may I ask why you need to delete one at a time?

Comment: this is my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475955/removing-entries-from-a-table-where-its-values-already-exist-in-the-table

Answer (score 1):

A set-oriented environment like SQL usually requires this kind of thing to happen "all at once".

You *might* be able to use a SQL DELETE statement within a transaction to delete a single row, with *that* transaction wrapped in a stored procedure to handle the logic, but that would be kind of like kicking dead whales down the beach.

You need the transaction (a committed transaction, maybe a serializable transaction) to reliably "free up" values, and to reliably handle concurrency and race conditions.